# PlayFab - creating a custom validation server for a card game

Tags: c#, validation, unity-game-engine, server

I want to use PlayFab to take care of authorization and database keeping in our game. But i also need a complex server-side validation logic for our combat.
It needs to know about player state(query db), run some complex game logic code, write to db and send result to client. Game is created via Unity5 and written in C#. My current options are:

- **PlayFab CloudScript**.  It is not practical to use it in my case becuase a) It's JavaScript and i want to have same code shared
  between in-game combat logics and server-side validation code. b)
  Even if i use some kind of translator from C# to JS, CloudScript has
  very strict limits on code size(50,000 bytes free, 200,000 bytes
  paid), which i am certainly going to exceed;
- **PlayFab Custom Game Server** This one looks promising, but i simply can't find enough information on how it exactly works. It has Unity
  SDK, but seems like an overkill to run an instance of Unity on a
  server when i don't need to simulate physics et c. I noticed PlayFab
  has [CSharpSDK](https://github.com/PlayFab/CSharpSDK) and it would be nice to have just a C# executable running on the server. Although it suggest to "please start with the
  included example project" in it's readme.md, i couldn't find any
  example project. Is it suitable for my purpose? How does it work
  exactly?
- **Own set of Dedicated Servers** If playfab is not suitable for my task, i'll just have to rent and setup servers, balancing et c. And
  run whatever i want there. But i'd like to avoid this hussle.
- **Your alternatives?**

What is the best wa to do that? And if you have any examples or extra info on PlayFab CSharpSDK, please provide it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Full disclosure: I run developer relations for PlayFab, so I'm often the person you'll see talking to devs in our own community forums.

While it does sound like you have much more computationally intensive needs than Cloud Script is really designed for, I'll start off by saying that we can actually increase the limits well beyond the base upgrade. If that's the direction you want to go, we can certainly discuss it - just open a ticket on our site, and I can talk with you about it.

In answer to your questions:

The example in the CSharpSDK repo is specifically the UnitTestRunner. It's designed to make the calls in the same way a title would - though I do see that we're only providing the combined SDK test runner, so I'll open a ticket with our tools team to get a Client API only version into the SDK.

Our custom game server hosting write-up is here: https://api.playfab.com/docs/custom-game-servers. In short, it's any game server code you want to write, running on (currently - definitely worth checking our updates later) Windows 2K12 servers in EC2. We have a basic server you can use as a start here (though it is indeed a Unity project, to be clear): https://github.com/PlayFab/PlayFabGameServer.

We'll also be providing a way to run your servers in other services, if you want to have your own contract with EC2, Softlayer, etc. The downside to that is that while it'll still integrate with our matchmaker, reporting, and log/output file capture systems, we won't be in control of server start/stop, so we won't be able to dynamically adjust the number of servers running on your behalf, the way we do in our own hosting. That update is expected for later this year. Sorry I can't be more precise, but as a live service, we have to adjust our schedule frequently and I don't ever want someone to take a dependency on a date we're not 100% confident

If you have any other questions about using PlayFab, I'd encourage posting in our forums, as we actively monitor them and answer questions there as soon as possible (though obviously, I check in on other sites like this one when I can). If your issue requires confidentiality, feel free to open a ticket and we'll get you the help you need.